Pyinstaller error: ImportError: cannot import name 'builder' from 'google.protobuf.internal'
Using pyinstaller(Auto-py-to-exe, exactly), I made my python application into exe file. In my application I used mediapipe module and I saw an error saying :
ImportError: cannot import name 'builder' from 'google.protobuf.internal' 

My application worked well in my pycharm environments. I searched web and found that I should downgrade protobuf==3.19.6, where the current version is 4.25.3. But I also saw an error message when I downgraded it,
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
mediapipe 0.10.14 requires protobuf<5,>=4.25.3, but you have protobuf 3.19.6 which is incompatible.

Is there any ways to evade this problem? Or should I restart from making exe file with another module, no pyinstaller of auto-py-to-exe ?
*P.S. : I made another simple mediapipe project, which uses mediapipe==0.10.11 and protobuf==3.20.3, and it also worked in pycharm environment and did not work when converted to exe by auto-py-to-exe. I'm quite sure that this is not version issue, but something deeper is required.

Try installing both libraries together in one line. This will force to install version of mediapipe that works with selected protobuf package. pip install --force-reinstall protobuf==3.19.6 mediapipe

@JohnnyCheesecutter Thank you for your kind advice. However it installed mediapipe==0.10.11 and it started to spit out same error even in pycharm environment. when I returned the version of protobuf it worked fine in pycharm.

I took another way to solve my problem.
I just used cx_freeze and all went well.
